# The event does not delete old records

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table and event `AutoDelete` to delete records which have not been updated for 3 Minute but it does not work I check `SHOW Variables` and `event_scheduler=on` I check `show processlist` and the state of the event  is `Waiting for next activation`. Can someone tell me where the problem is.

```
        stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bus"
                + "(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
                + "route int(11) NOT NULL,"
                + "latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,"
                + "longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,"
                + "created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

        stt.execute("CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS  AutoDelete "
                + "ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE "
                + "DO "
                + "DELETE FROM bus WHERE created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)");

        stt.execute("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON");
```

Comment: what about `show events` ?

Comment: Are you sure the where clause is right and you can run the query directly?

Comment: @pala__ show events: bustracker
AutoDelete
root@localhost
SYSTEM
RECURRING
NULL
3
MINUTE
2015-05-19 01:01:32
NULL
ENABLED
1
latin1
latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: @tim38880: yes it works ia have already tested it.